# How to check one table is overlapping with already existing table in Word

Tags: ms-word, overlapping

Can anyone tell how to know one table is getting overlapped with another table (existing table) while inserting.

Assume I have already inserted Table1 and while inserting Table2, It is getting Overlapped with table1, But Code wise after inserting Table2, is there any way to check Table2 is Overlapping/Overridden on Table1?